# Function with the_author_posts_link returns link out of order in WordPress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written a function for my WordPress theme to output the Author's name and post date. It runs inside the Loop.

```
$author = the_author_posts_link();
$date = get_the_date( 'j/n/y' );
echo '<span>Posted by </span><span>';
echo $author;
echo '</span><span> on</span><span> ' . $date . '</span>';
```

It is outputting this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/author/root/" title="Posts by root" rel="author">root</a>
<span>Posted by </span>
<span></span>
<span> on</span>
<span> 4/12/13</span>
```

The problem is that the Author link is output first and not where I expect it, which is causing formatting issues. No matter what I've tried, it returns the `<a>` before any of the other echoed code. No adjustments to the HTML seem to work - it looks like I have to handle this in PHP, but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [the_author_posts_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link) display out the link.

If you look at this link

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/author-template.php#L0

The function `the_author_posts_link` is echoing out the link instead of returning, So Change your code to:

```
$date = get_the_date( 'j/n/y' );
echo '<span>Posted by </span><span>';
the_author_posts_link();
echo '</span><span> on</span><span> ' . $date . '</span>';
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! I think I tried that, but left `$author = the_author_posts_link();` in, which also spat out the link.